# Problem with downloading pdf with curl in php. Downloaded file is damaged

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I'm downloading a pdf file trough curl. But when I try to open the downloaded file from the website, it gives the error in adobe that the file is damaged.

I tried a lot of different things according to similar questions that I found on here but it stays the same. With the api I'm using it creates the pdf local and then send the response. If I try the url in Postman, I can see the pdf in the response.

The pdf that is created locally I can also open without problems.

Now if I just echo the result I get this from the pdf:

> %PDF-1.7 4 0 obj << /BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /Filter /DCTDecode /Height 101 /Length 5624 /Subtype /Image /Type /XObject /Width 399 >> stream ...

This is my code:

```
  $ch = curl_init($remote_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remote_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$token));

  // Execute the request
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  // Close cURL resource
  curl_close($ch);

  header('Cache-Control: public'); 
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="response.pdf"');
  header('Content-Length: '.strlen($result));
  echo $result;
```

I'm not finding the correct code so my pdf isn't damaged anymore. Any tips of what I can do?

Thank you!

EDIT: If I open my downloaded pdf with notepad I see that the html of my header of the site is also in the pdf. So the pdf starts with <!doctype html>

EDIT 2: For my pages I require a header.php so it shows the navbar etc. If I comment out the require 'header.php'; in my code, the pdf is downloaded correctly. Then it opens te pdf without error. But I have no idea how the header.php is coming into my pdf file

EDIT 3: code from the header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <?php
        if(empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
            echo '<h2>Log in om de reparaties te bekijken.</h2>
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="index.php" role="button">Log in</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<h2>Bekijk de reparaties</h2>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="home.php" role="button">Home</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="newrepair-view.php" role="button">Nieuwe reparatie</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="repairs-view.php" role="button">Alle reparaties</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="repairsinprogress-view.php" role="button">Uit te voeren reparaties</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="repaired-view.php" role="button">Uitgevoerde reparaties</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="repairsdone-view.php" role="button">Afgewerkte reparaties</a> 
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="./" role="button">Log out</a>';
        }
        ?>    
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If the output starts with `<!doctype html>`, where does this come from?

Comment: Maybe download PDF, to begin with? Or send a `401` header ...

Comment: `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` might be wrong.

Comment: @NicoHaase for my pages I require a header.php so it shows the navbar etc. If I comment out the require 'header.php'; in my code, the pdf is downloaded correctly. Then it opens te pdf without error. But I have no idea how the header.php is coming into my pdf file.

Comment: Well, we don't either, as you haven't shared such code. Why not debug that problem, either by using XDebug and setting a breakpoint, or by using debug_backtrace?

Comment: I don't know what more code I should show? The code that I shared is downloading and opening the pdf so it's in that part that I'm looking.

I just commented out ```require 'header.php'; so this isn't anymore on my page and then it doesn't come in my pdf.

Comment: Either remove the code that includes the header on your own, or share more details if you struggle with resolving the problem. In the current state, nobody can tell you what to do, as you haven't shared the code that causes the problem

Comment: I edited my post and shared the code of my header.php. If this is there it comes in my pdf, if it's not then it just shows the pdf correctly.

Comment: If removing it resolves the problem, remove it. If this causes new problems, fix the header properly - if you don't want to receive it in front of a PDF output, check where the header is included and don't include it

Comment: The problem is I can not remove it because this header.php containts the layout and navbar for every page. So I need it also for this page.

I think my problem is inside of "header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="response.pdf"');". It should not take the whole page but only the string of $result. And that's not happening right now.

I'm still searching for the right code without removing the header.php. I will post it here if I find it and every tip is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "for this page"? If that page **should** return a PDF file that everybody can open, it should **not** contain any HTML markup. Have you tried to check why this occurs here?

Comment: This page contains a form with information from a repairdocument. And I added a button PDF. So if they click the button, it needs to download the pdf with this information and open the pdf. But only if they click the button.

Comment: Yes. That should be a completely seperate request, and this does not need any HTML markup